# Android Video Playback Speed

Tags: android, video, playback

I'm building a custom video player in Android and it needs to be able to adjust video playback speed. I know Android's MediaPlayer doesn't have anything built-in to do that, but does anyone know of a good library out there that can do that?

I'm trying out Vitamio right now. However, I read that it has a few limitations, but I couldn't find what those limitations are. Has anyone worked with Vitamio and would you recommend it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't been able to find all the limitations for Vitamio, but for playback speed control, it works fine (as long as you stay within .5x and 2x speeds).

Link to Vitamio: https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/

It's not super well documented, so it took me a while to figure it out, but their download does include a sample project for you to poke at.